# Nested subquery in Oracle is slow

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with three fields: `ID`, `date` and `action`. The three possible values of `action` are `X`, `Y` and `Z`. I want a query which, for each `ID` in the table for which there ia a row with a `Z` action, will return the most recent row for the same `ID` with an `X` action, if one exists.

Here is what I want to do in MySQL. I copy-and-pasted the code from [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com), so I know it works.

```
create table a (id int,
              date int,
              action varchar(1));

insert into a values(1, 1, 'X');
insert into a values(1, 2, 'X');
insert into a values(1, 3, 'Z');
insert into a values(2, 1, 'X');
insert into a values(2, 2, 'Y');
insert into a values(2, 3, 'Y');
insert into a values(2, 4, 'Z');
insert into a values(3, 1, 'X');
insert into a values(3, 2, 'Y');
insert into a values(3, 3, 'X');
insert into a values(3, 4, 'Z');
insert into a values(4, 3, 'X');


SELECT a.id,
       max(a.date) as Xdate,
       b.date as Zdate,
       a.action FROM a,

               (SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.action = 'Z') b
                WHERE
                    a.date < b.date AND
                    a.ID = b.ID AND
                    a.action = 'X'
                GROUP BY a.id;
```

I can't use the `GROUP BY` clause with other fields like this in Oracle, so I did a nested subquery which found the maximum date for each ID separately, but it is very slow (I am expecting to get about 10^5 rows) and I was hoping that there was a better way to do it which would be faster. (I can't post my actual Oracle query at the moment because it does not run in SQLfiddle; it keeps complaining about rows being ambiguously defined.)

Can the above query be made to work in Oracle somehow? If not, is there an equivalent way to do it which will run in a reasonable time?

Comment: Your query do not works because you can not use the name `date` as field name, anyway, after correcting this, the query do not works too. Please correct it, and post the correct query to understand what you want.

Comment: Please try this query [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/adc50/7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works (although it may be able to be simplified):

```
SELECT a.id,
       max(a."date") as Xdate,
       b."date" as Zdate,
       a.action 
FROM a INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT * 
   FROM a 
   WHERE a.action = 'Z') b
  ON a.ID = b.ID 
WHERE a."date" < b."date" 
   AND a.action = 'X'
GROUP BY a.id, b."date", a.action
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd704/1)

Please note, you need to use `"` around reserved words -- in this case the column `date`.  You also need to add all of your fields to the `GROUP BY` clause.  MySQL allows it without, but Oracle does not.

---

Edit, simplified version:

```
SELECT a.Id, max(a."date"), b."date", a.action
FROM a
  INNER JOIN a b ON a.Id = b.Id AND b.action = 'Z'
WHERE a.action = 'X' 
  AND a."date" < b."date"
GROUP BY a.Id, b."date", a.action
```

- [Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd704/3)

Comment: +1 for the `join` instead of subquery. I'd also move `a."date" < b."date"` into the `ON ...` clause of the join, but it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. I will try it out when I get to work tomorrow. I was aware of the date thing, but sqlfiddle didn't seem to mind as long as the default MySQL 5.5.32 option was used.

Comment: @Flounderer Be careful with using MySQL to debug your Oracle queries: MySQL is often more relaxed about group by queries that seem basic. You should switch to your RDBMS of choice when demonstrating queries there.

Comment: This was very helpful. The query is still timing out but it is faster. Are there any other tricks which could speed it up more?

Answer (score 1):

Here other solution:

```
WITH temp AS (
     SELECT a.id, a.date_f, a.action FROM a WHERE a.action = 'Z'
)
SELECT a.id,
       max(a.date_f) as Xdate,
       temp.date_f as Zdate,
       a.action
FROM a
INNER JOIN temp ON temp.id = a.id AND a.date_f < temp.date_f
WHERE a.action = 'X'
GROUP BY a.id,temp.date_f,a.action;
```

**Note**: date_f is the field date.
**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/adc50/10)**.

Answer (score 0):

One problem trying to go between MySQL and Oracle is that Oracle is simply much more powerful.

You can solve your problem using analytic functions in Oracle.  These are not available in MySQL.

Here is the Oracle solution:

```
select a.id, a.thedate as Xdate, a.ZDate
from (select a.*,
             min(case when action = 'Z' then thedate end) over
                 (partition by id
                  order by thedate
                  rows between current row and unbounded following
                 ) as Zdate,
             row_number() over (partition by id, action
                                order by thedate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a
where a.action = 'X' and a.seqnum = 1;
```

You can see it on SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6ca4/10).